# Angular 6: Map JSON from inside

Tags: json, angular, dictionary

I have code like this:

```
export class ClientSearchService extends QueryService {

  private a = [
    {
      'firstName': 'Danuta',
      'lastName': 'Kowalska',
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'ADAM',
      'lastName': 'Kowalski',
    }
  ];

  private b = {
    'something': [
      {
        'firstName': 'Danuta',
        'lastName': 'Kowalska',
      },
      {
        'firstName': 'ADAM',
        'lastName': 'Kowalski',
      }
    ]
  };


  public list() {

    const testA = of(this.a);
    testA.pipe(
      map((records: Client[]) => records.map((client: Client) => Client.factory(client)))
    ).subscribe(records => {
      console.log(records);
    });

    const testB = of(this.b);
    testB.pipe(
    map(XXXX).subscribe(records => {
       console.log(records);
    });
  }
}
```

Test (A) is correct. I get array of Client objects in console.

In my second example (B) I have JSON with Clients data but inside 'somethig' key.
What should I change to map this JSON on Client class ?

Comment: Just `map(data => data.something)` before your normal mapping.

Comment: `const testB = of(this.b.something);`

Comment: Can I do this in one map line ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
    const testB = of(this.b.something);
```